# Re-Try Execute Process Task on Failure

Tags: ssis

I have Sequence Container comprising of multiple execute process task in one sequence.

For example
EPT1 -> EPT2 -> EPT3.

Now I need to learn two things from this flow.

1) If Execute Process Task 2 fails then Re-Try it 2 more times. Even after trying two more times make the task fails.
2) If the Execute Process Task 2 fails, I still need to execute process task 3 as well as  need some mechanism do drop an email or create a log file about error in the Execute Process Task 2.

Answer (score 0):

Put Execute Package Task in a For Loop Container. Define a variable, which will do the count, one for a successrun indicator and a MAX_COUNT Constance. In properties of the Package Task - Expressions, define

```
FailPackageOnFailure - False
```

After Execute Task put a Script Task Read/Write Vars: SuccessfulRun, script:

```
Dts.Variables["SuccessfulRun"].Value = 1
```

In properties of the For Loop:

```
InitExpression - @Val_Counter = 0
EvalExpression - @Counter < @MAX_COUNT && @SuccessfulRun == 0
AssingExpression - @Val_Counter = @Val_Counter + 1
Connect PackageTask with ScriptTask using Success line.
```

OR

In For Loop Container define expression

```
MaximumErrorCount - Const_MAX_COUNT
```

But this one hasn't been tested by me yet...